# Issue with ORDER BY not sorting properly with sub selects

Tags: mysql, sql

In the SQL statement below the results are returned out of order. If they were in ascending or descending order it would make sense, but it seems there is no order here.

Any insights as to why the ORDER BY function isn't sorting by the 'date' alias would be very much appreciated.

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT id, date, type 
    FROM (SELECT resume_id AS id, DATE_FORMAT( date_mod, '%M %e, %Y' ) AS date, 'resume' AS TYPE 
              FROM resumes 
              WHERE user_id = '$user_id' 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT profile_id, DATE_FORMAT( date_mod, '%M %e, %Y' ) AS date, 'profile' 
              FROM profiles 
              WHERE user_id = '$user_id' 
          ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5) AS d1 
    ORDER BY date
```

Results:

```
Resume was updated on February 14, 2012
Resume was updated on February 15, 2012
Resume was updated on February 15, 2012
Resume was updated on February 9, 2012
Profile was updated on February 9, 2012
```

Comment: It is sorting properly, because the inner query is returning a date STRING, not a date FIELD.

Comment: You have what looks like a small bug, probably inconsequential but still worth pointing out. You are selecting `resume_id AS id` in the first inner query, but just `profile_id` in the second one. That should be `profile_id AS id`. In your case you are not using the id, so it doesn't matter, but could be an annoying bug down the line if you do end up using the id. In the second query you are also just selecting `'profile'` instead of `'profile' AS type`. (I made these fixes in the answer I posted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sorting them as strings because you've converted the dates to strings using `DATE_FORMAT` (note that as a string "February 15..." is lower than "February 9..." because 1 comes before 9 in the "alphabet"). The solution is to sort by the real date in `date_mod`. You could do it directly by just adding in `date_mod` to the selects and changing the order, like this:

```
SELECT id, date, date_mod, type
FROM (
  SELECT resume_id AS id,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_mod, '%M %e, %Y') AS date,
    date_mod,
    'resume' AS type
  FROM resumes
  WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT profile_id AS id,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_mod, '%M %e, %Y') AS date,
    date_mod,
    'profile' AS type
  FROM profiles
  WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
  ORDER BY date_mod DESC
  LIMIT 5
) AS d1
ORDER BY date_mod
```

But even better would be to simplify it by selecting *only* `date_mod` in the sub-query (i.e. no formatted version) and doing the `DATE_FORMAT` last in the outer query:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date_mod, '%M %e, %Y') AS date, type
FROM (
  SELECT resume_id AS id, date_mod, 'resume' AS type
  FROM resumes
  WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT profile_id AS id, date_mod, 'profile' AS type
  FROM profiles
  WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
  ORDER BY date_mod DESC
  LIMIT 5
) AS d1
ORDER BY date_mod
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben, the concept makes perfect sense, it's sorting based on the date string, not the date_mod field.

Answer (score 1):

It's ordering your formatted date strings as strings, and you want to order them as dates.  I would order by `date_mod` directly, then convert the output in the `SELECT` clause.